# my code isnt storing data value into Sql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i wrote a code to store values of textbox into sql database and it worked fine but when i tried to insert values of datagridview into sql database, neither it worked nor it returned error.....

```
Private Sub savenprint()
        If Not db.con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            db.dbOpen()
            With db.cmd
                .Connection = db.con
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Reciept VALUES ('" & txtRecieptNo.Text & "','" & TransDate.Text & "','" & txtSubTotal.Text & "') "
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            'to save data of DGVOrderedList into RecieptDescription
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGVorderedList.Rows

                MsgBox(row.Cells(1).Value)
                With db.cmd
                    .Connection = db.con
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO billDescription VALUES ('" & Val(txtRecieptNo.Text) & "','" & row.Cells(1).Value & "','" & row.Cells(2).Value & "','" & row.Cells(4).Value & "','" & row.Cells(3).Value & "','" & row.Cells(5).Value & "')"
                End With
                MsgBox("Record Saved!")
            Next



        End If
        db.dbClose()
    End Sub
```

Comment: use sql parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            With db.cmd
                .Connection = db.con
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO billDescription VALUES ('" & Val(txtRecieptNo.Text) & "','" & row.Cells(1).Value & "','" & row.Cells(2).Value & "','" & row.Cells(4).Value & "','" & row.Cells(3).Value & "','" & row.Cells(5).Value & "')"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
```